# Find the most synchronizable array

Tags: python, arrays, list

Let's say I have a 20s video with points I want to synchronize at 5s, 10s, and 15s :

```
video = [5, 10, 15]
```

I have *k* (here 7) musics that have different sync points:

```
musics = [[2.009, 4.005, 6.002, 7.999, 9.996, 11.993, 14.002],
         [2.009, 4.005, 6.002, 7.999, 9.996, 11.993],
         [2.009, 4.005, 6.002],
         [1.498, 5.503, 7.5, 9.497, 11.494, 13.502],
         [2.02, 4.017, 6.014, 8.011],
         [3.495, 5.503, 7.5, 9.497, 11.494, 13.491],
         [1.498, 3.495, 5.503, 7.5, 9.497, 11.494, 13.502, 15.499]]
```

I have the right to stretch a part (example: from 0 to 2.009 or from 0 to 4.005 ) up to 10%.
What would be the best way to find the music you can stretch that will sync best?

I tried :

```
import numpy as np

test = []
stretch = 0.10
tmp = 0
for music in musics:
    tmp = 0
    new_line = []
    for music_sync_point in music:
        for video_sync_point in video:
            if np.isclose(music_sync_point, video_sync_point, atol=(music_sync_point - tmp) * stretch):
                new_line.append(music_sync_point)
                tmp = music_sync_point
    test.append(new_line)
```

output :

```
>>> test
[[9.996], [9.996], [], [5.503], [], [5.503], [5.503, 15.499]]
```

According to the output, the 7th music is the most synchronizable and we can stretch the part
(0 - 5.503) *to* (0 - 5)
*and*
(5.503 - 15.499) *to* (5.503 - 15)
This makes us synchronize 2 points

But I know it's not optimal, any ideas ?

Comment: Anyone, any ideas ?